# Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup vs Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup?

Tags: setup-script

What;s the difference between these two? Can't find an answers anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base setup classes for `flat tables`  are `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` and EAV entities `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`.

`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` is  used for non eav module and report and product alert
admin modules table creation  and it work on single table

`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` is eav structural module. for customer ,product ,category module table creation and it work on multiple table

See at http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1

Comment: Will Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup work in all cases where Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup works?

Comment: Yes, it will - it's a child.